# Convert a matrix of syms to doubles

Tags: matlab

I've got a problem where I need to use the Jacobian of a function r. r is a vector [x1*exp(x2*t)], Where t is a vector t = [0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0];

To calculate this I've done

```
syms x1 x2
r = [x1*exp(x2*t)];

jacobian(r)

ans =

[     exp(x2/2),       (x1*exp(x2/2))/2]
[       exp(x2),             x1*exp(x2)]
[ exp((3*x2)/2), (3*x1*exp((3*x2)/2))/2]
[     exp(2*x2),         2*x1*exp(2*x2)]
[ exp((5*x2)/2), (5*x1*exp((5*x2)/2))/2]
[     exp(3*x2),         3*x1*exp(3*x2)]
[ exp((7*x2)/2), (7*x1*exp((7*x2)/2))/2]
[     exp(4*x2),         4*x1*exp(4*x2)]
```

Is there an easy way to convert this matrix into a matrix of values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just substitute values using `subs`.

```
 >> subs(ans, [x1, x2], [1.4, 2.5])

ans =

[ exp(5/4),   (7*exp(5/4))/10]
[ exp(5/2),    (7*exp(5/2))/5]
[exp(15/4), (21*exp(15/4))/10]
[   exp(5),     (14*exp(5))/5]
[exp(25/4),   (7*exp(25/4))/2]
[exp(15/2),  (21*exp(15/2))/5]
[exp(35/4), (49*exp(35/4))/10]
[  exp(10),    (28*exp(10))/5]
```

This is still of `class` `sym`, but you can then convert to double using `double`

```
double(ans)

ans =

   1.0e+05 *

    0.0000    0.0000
    0.0001    0.0002
    0.0004    0.0009
    0.0015    0.0042
    0.0052    0.0181
    0.0181    0.0759
    0.0631    0.3092
    0.2203    1.2335
```